# PHP/MySQL: Login page isn't working please check

Tags: php, mysql, html

I created this login page that checks whether the entered username and password matches a record in the users table. But whenever I click on the submit button, nothing happens. What is the error? Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['tsmUsername'])) {
            $username=$_POST['tsmUsername'];
            $_SESSION['tsmUserName']=$username;
            $password=$_POST['tsmPassword'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users cust_registration WHERE custName='$username' AND custPass='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $result=mysql_query($dbconnect,$sql);
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
        {
            echo "You have successfully logged in";

        }
        else{
            echo "Invalid";
        }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> THE CAR  PARK</title>
    <centre><div class="a1">
        <h3 style="color:crimson" align="centre"> WELCOME TO THE </h3>      
        </div></centre>
<centre>    <div class="a2">

<h1 style="color:crimson" align="centre"> PARK MARK </h1>

        </div></centre>
<hr>    <br>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Coding Cage - Login & Registration System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>


    <body background="user4.png"  height="auto" width="auto" bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

<div class="form">
<div class="container">

 <div align="center" id="login-form">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" autocomplete="off">

     <div class="col-md-12">

         <div class="form-group">
             <h2 style="color:crimson" class="">LOGIN</h2>
            </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <hr />
            </div>

            <?php
   if ( isset($errMSG) ) {

    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
             <div class="alert alert-<?php echo ($errTyp=="success") ? "success" : $errTyp; ?>">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $errMSG; ?>
                </div>
             </div>
                <?php
   }
   ?>



            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
            <centre><p style="color:crimson">Username</p> <input type="text" name="tsmUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $name ?>" /></centre>
                </div>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
             <centre><p style="color:crimson">Password</p><input type="password" name="tsmPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" maxlength="15" /></centre>
                </div>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo $passError; ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <hr />
            </div>

      <tr>      <div class="form-group">
             <centre><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="submit">log in</button></centre>
            </div>
     <div class="hd5">

         <button><a href="welcome.php">Back To Home>></a></button>
         <button><a href="cust_register.php">Customer registration</a></button>
        <button><a href="location.php">Location</a></button>
        <button><a href="parking.php">Parking</a></button>
        <button><a href="accounts.php">Accounts</a></button>
            </div>
             <hr />

            </tr>


        </div>

    </form>
    </div> 

</div>
    </div>


</body>

<header>
    <h5 align="right" style=color:antiquewhite>Designed by: john</h5>


  </header>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: what happens when you are click the submit button?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make surey ou ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: you don't need action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"

By default, the form will load the same page

Comment: @t-n-y thanks but it still isnt working.. getting this error Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\car_park\users.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\car_park\users.php on line 11

Comment: table name has space.enter valid table name without space in your sql query

Comment: @JayBlanchard yea thts the error i am getting

Comment: `value="<?php echo $name ?>"` you should be getting an undefined variable notice here and `<centre></centre>` are invalid tags. They should read as `<center></center>` respectively, however those tags are deprecated.

Comment: @denny there isnt any space.. its cust_register

Comment: which api are you using to connect with also, `mysql_` right? If other, than that's failing you.

Comment: what do you mean "users"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. will that fix the issue?

Comment: I don't know, try it. Also this `if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)` if you have more than one row matching in db and what you're trying to login as, would also fail. So it's best to use `if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)` - the `==1` is looking if there is only 1 record.

Comment: @denny its the name of this file users.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok will try hang on. plz dont go anywhere lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- is still not working :/ still getting the warning error

Comment: I asked earlier which api you used to connect with, is `mysql_` or `mysqli_` or PDO? did you use the right connection credentials? The error I saw in comments suggests that you didn't connect properly. If you assigned a variable to the connection, and if you are using `mysql_` to connect with, then `mysql_query()` would probably need an argument for it. I.e.: `mysql_query($connection)`. In other words, your query failed `mysql_error()` for the connection and the query.

Comment: hold on here,  I just noticed this now:  `$result=mysql_query($dbconnect,$sql);` you need to invert those `$result=mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect);` the connection in mysql_ comes second, not first. That's if your connection is mysql_.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea sorry forgot to mention that.. yes i am using mysql_ oh so all i need is to include mysql_query($connection) and thats it? sorry new to php so its a bit confusing. So i have to erase any lines and put this code .. Can u demonstrate the php part plz :/

Comment: I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after many comments... (to which I noticed the following):

`$result=mysql_query($dbconnect,$sql);`

You need to invert those two variables:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect);
```

The connection in mysql_ comes second, not first.

I also won't repeat what's already been said in comments by everyone else, including mine.

---

**Edit:**

Here's a quick rewrite in mysqli_ to help you out.

```
<?php

    error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE ); 

    define('DBHOST', 'localhost'); 
    define('DBUSER', 'root'); 
    define('DBPASS', ''); 
    define('DBNAME', 'car_park'); 
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME); 

    if ( !$conn ) { die("Connection failed : " . mysqli_error($conn)); }
?>


<?php
session_start();
// place the db connection stuff above inside your dbconnect.php after
// include 'dbconnect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['tsmUsername'])) {
            $username=$_POST['tsmUsername'];
            $_SESSION['tsmUserName']=$username;
            $password=$_POST['tsmPassword'];

        $sql="SELECT * FROM users cust_registration 
              WHERE custName='$username' 
              AND custPass='$password' LIMIT 1";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        } // brace for if (!empty($_POST['tsmUsername']))

        if($result){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
            {
                echo "You have successfully logged in";

            }
            else{
                echo "Invalid"; 
                }
        } // brace for if($result)
            else {
                echo "The query failed: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }

  }
?>
```

But do use a prepared statement for this, your code is open to an SQL injection, and `password_hash()` as already stated in comments. It only makes good sense, especially in this day and age.

---

And if you're still wanting to use the mysql_ API:

dbconnect.php:

```
<?php 

    error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE ); 

    define('DBHOST', 'localhost'); 
    define('DBUSER', 'root'); 
    define('DBPASS', ''); 
    define('DBNAME', 'car_park'); 

    $conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS); 
    $dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $conn); 

    if ( !$conn ) { die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error($conn)); } 
    if ( !$dbcon ) { die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error($conn)); } 

?>
```

PHP/MySQL:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Put the above codes in the dbconnect.php file
include 'dbconnect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['tsmUsername'])) {
            $username=$_POST['tsmUsername'];
            $_SESSION['tsmUserName']=$username;
            $password=$_POST['tsmPassword'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users cust_registration 
              WHERE custName='$username' 
              AND custPass='$password' LIMIT 1";

        $result=mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        if($result){
            echo "OK, the query did not fail.";
        }
        else{
            echo "The query failed: " . mysql_error($conn);
        }

        if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            echo "You have successfully logged in";

        }
        else{
            echo "Invalid";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: this getting the same issue :( those two warnings.. i tried removing dbconnect and just put $sql with mysql_query and the warning became only 1.. However in both cases i am still getting warnings :/

Comment: @DavidAdam what version of php are you using? the exact version. and what is the code you used to connect with? did you choose the right database also?

Comment: <?php

 // this will avoid mysql_connect() deprecation error.
 error_reporting( ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
 // but I strongly suggest you to use PDO or MySQLi.
 
 define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
 define('DBUSER', 'root');
 define('DBPASS', '');
 define('DBNAME', 'car_park');
 
 $conn = mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS);
 $dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME);
 
 if ( !$conn ) {
  die("Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
 }
 
 if ( !$dbcon ) {
  die("Database Connection failed : " . mysql_error());
 }

Comment: `$conn` you used the wrong variable then for the query. You had `$dbconnect` where it should have been `$conn` same for `$dbcon`

Comment: thing is this dbconnect worked for every other page except login

Comment: ohh let me fix that

Comment: Use `$result=mysql_query($sql, $conn);` that should make it kick into high gear

Comment: and `$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $conn);`

Comment: oh so u mean like this :- $sql="SELECT * FROM users cust_registration WHERE custName='$username' AND custPass='$password' LIMIT 1";
  $result=mysql_query($sql, $conn);
   $dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $conn);
  if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
  {
   echo "You have successfully logged in";
   
  }
  else{
   echo "Invalid";
  }

Comment: btw thanksa lot for helping. Will surely give u approval once it starts working

Comment: `$dbcon = mysql_select_db(DBNAME, $conn);` that should be included in the db connection first. Give me a minute, I'll do up a rewrite in `mysqli_` and post it under my answer. Mysql_ shouldn't be used anymore

Comment: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\car_park\users.php on line 12

Comment: Reload my answer and look under **Edit:**, best I can for you here and that should work, I can't see it failing. If it did fail, then you will have to check for errors, it's all in there.

Comment: @DavidAdam You're welcome David, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_select_db($dbconnect);
mysql_query($sql);
```

**OR**

```
mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
```